# Create url/link that runs specific javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a blog set up with homepage that loads the blog entries into the page when the title is clicked (using a javascript function).  I would like to be able to send someone a link to a specific entry.  In essence is there a way to have a URL that runs enters the the article name into the function.  I know this probably doesn't exist so is there a way to achieve this, if not how should I set up my website so that I don't have 50 replications of the 'shell' at each url with the only thing changing is the text inside one element.

Here is a truncated version of the code.

```
function addArticle (articleName){
    var ourRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    currentArticleId = articleName;

    ourRequest.open('GET', 'https://x.neocities.org/' + articleName +'.html');

    ourRequest.onload = function(){
      var blogPost = ourRequest.responseText;
      document.getElementById("on_display").innerHTML = blogPost;
    };

    ourRequest.send();
}
```

Note: I have each article stored in its own url which this script grabs.

Thanks for the help!